# Spring integration xml file errors out on reactor StringUtils

Tags: spring-integration, project-reactor

I have a spring integration sftp flow which I load as a child context within my overall application context. This is based on the [dynamic ftp SI example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp). My integration flow has nothing about reactor or streams in it. Its a simple flow with one `direct channel` connected with a `sftp-outbound-gateway` to transfer files to a sftp server. I can even run units tests and the flow work fine (is able to transfer files) but when I run an integration test which loads the full parent application and then initializes the child context with this sftp flow loaded in it, it throws an error for not being able to find reactor/StringUtils class.

The reason for that seems to be that spring-integration-sftp loads reactor jars as transient deps but since my parent application already has a different version of reactor loaded in the classpath I excluded the reactor-core from spring integration dep. If I dont exclude the reactor-core from spring-integration then there are some version conflicts so I would like to exclude it.

```
reactorVersion = 2.0.0.M2

compile("io.projectreactor:reactor-core:$reactorVersion")
compile "io.projectreactor.spring:reactor-spring-context:$reactorVersion"

compile("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-sftp") {
    exclude module: "reactor-core"
}
```

Initializing the SI flow

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "classpath:adapters/"
                + sink.getConfigurationFile() }, false);
        setEnvironment(context, sink);
        context.setParent(parentContext);
        context.refresh();
        context.registerShutdownHook();
```

The error when i ran the integration test

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [adapters/sftp.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/util/StringUtils
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)

Finally the SI flow

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp.xsd">

<import resource="common.xml" />

<bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="defaultSftpSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="defaultSftpSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${sink.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="22" />
    <property name="privateKey" value="${sink.private.key}" />
    <property name="privateKeyPassphrase" value="${sink.private.key.phrase}" />
    <property name="user" value="${sink.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${sink.pass}" />
</bean>

<int:channel id="input" />

<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter
    auto-startup="true" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" channel="input"
    remote-directory="${sink.path}" remote-filename-generator-expression="headers['remote_file_name']">
    <int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload" />
            <property name="successChannel" ref="successChannel" />
            <property name="onFailureExpression" value="payload" />
            <property name="failureChannel" ref="failureChannel" />
            <property name="trapException" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="successChannel" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="successChannel"
    ref="completionHandler" method="handle" />

<int:channel id="failureChannel" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="failureChannel"
    ref="failureHandler" method="handle" />
```

---

Updating to add my reactor configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactor
public class ReactorConfiguration {

static {
    Environment.initializeIfEmpty().assignErrorJournal();
}

@Bean
public EventBus eventBus() {
    return EventBus.config().env(Environment.get()).dispatcher(Environment.SHARED).get();
}

@Bean
public IdGenerator randomUUIDGenerator() {
    return new IdGenerator() {
        @Override
        public UUID generateId() {
            return UUIDUtils.random();
        }
    };
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle currently doesn't do a great job excluding dependencies of transitive dependencies.

It's not `spring-integration-sftp` that pulls in reactor, it's `spring-integration-core`.

Try explicitly excluding via that.

We have removed the hard transitive reactor dependency in SI 4.2 (but it's not released yet).

The spring team has created a [gradle plugin](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin) that might help.

Comment: actually its not just excluding reactor from spring integration. It seems SI is using version `1.1.4` of `reactor` where `StringUtils` class is in utils package and in the newer `2.0.0.M2` version of reactor (where most of spring support is provided) has StringUtils in `reactor.core.support` package.

Comment: If I let the reactor 1.1.4 be included along with spring-integration-core then I run into this error. `No Dispatcher found for name 'shared', it must be present in the configuration properties or being registered programmatically through this#addDispatcher(shared, someDispatcher)`. Why does this happens. Any ideas

Comment: All the packages/maven coordinates were changed in reactor2 to enable them to coexist on the classpath, so I doubt it's simply the presence of 1.1.4 - have you tried [2.0.0.RELEASE](http://projectreactor.io/)?