# spring integration sftp with reactor

Tags: spring, spring-integration, project-reactor

This question is sort of continuation of a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929766/spring-integration-xml-file-errors-out-on-reactor-stringutils) that I posted. I wanted to create a github project to confirm the behavior and possibly figure out some kind of resolution. Here is the [github project](https://github.com/adeelmahmood/spring-int-reactor-sftp)

Spring support for reactor seems to be included in reactor 2.x versions and spring integration sftp uses 1.1.4 version of reactor and references a StringUtils class which has been moved to a different package in reactor 2+ versions.

It seems that this version conflict is simply unavoidable until its resolved in SI 4.2 so I am hoping to get some suggestions on how I can use reactor 1.1.4 and recreate the same/similar reactor configuration as I have with spring reactor support (in this project). This way SI sftp will work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reactor `2.0.0.RELEASE` work was done on 2.0 to make the packages/maven coordinates orthogonal so both versions can coexist on the classpath.

I am not sure if the work was complete by milestone 2.

Comment: Thank you - that finally did it. So basically I use reactor 2.0.0.RELEASE in parent context and let spring integration bring in reactor 1.1.4.RELEASE as well and for now both seem to coexist peacefully. I guess it will automatically get better once SI 4.2 comes out. Thanks again